# Does Android trust StartSSL certificates?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am developing an Android app and I would like to encrypt the data sent to my server. I've seen many people saying that the best practices are using SSL and I found that StartSSL is free. My questions are:

1. Would Android trust my StartSSL certificate?
2. Do you recommend me StartSSL or should I use another Certificate Authority like RapidSSL or GoDaddy?

Thanks!

Comment: StartSSL is dead, distrusted by Chrome, FF, Apple; and they do not issue certificates anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the certificate is valid and complete (**with intermediate certificate**), yes it will work.

Get more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888353/603270

2. That is subjective.

Answer (score -3):

I personally got my certificate here:

https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/domain-validation.aspx

It was the cheapest i could find and i havent gotten into any trust issues. (ios, android, chrome, firefox, IE)

Just make sure your certificate chain is setup correctly.